# Fixed background position on flexible layout

Tags: javascript, html, css

In short, I want a fixed background position relative to an element on a flexible layout.

http://devwp.steveforest.com/

So the background remains well positioned to the dark gray sidebar at the left if you change the screen size. The correct position is as it is right now if you put the browser to ~1920px wide.

The only way I found so far is to use a lot of "@media screen and (min-width:Xpx)" in CSS but that's not pretty (and using a lot of lines in my CSS) and perfectly fluid.

Is there a better way to achieve that? I don't mind using javascript/jQuery.

Comment: I would place it in an absolute positioned div and have its left with the same percentage as the left bar. You may be able to achieve this with positioning the backgound with a percentage but it is tricky.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally cut the background image in two pieces. Place the right piece on your right side and position it to the left and place the left side to the left and position it to the right.